# What does my professor mean by "Implementing a static Abstract Data Type"?

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

In my class for our assignment we are making two different Abstract Data Types, `Double Stack` and `Leaky Stack`. I have no problem creating these, but my professor put in the assignment details for both of these ADTs to "Give an efficient static implementation of the ADT". But what the hell does that mean? I could ask him tomorrow, but I want to get this assignment done today. Anyone have any idea what he means by this?

Comment: Has any recent discussion been around BigO notation or dynamic allocation?

Comment: Well all of our methods need to be of O(1). Except for our toString and equals method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible interpretation is that the solutions are to use a fixed size "static" underlying structure (such as an array), rather than using a dynamic growing amount. Each stack, therefore, would have a pre-assigned maximum capacity. Therefore, I would expect an exception to be thrown on a `push(...)` operation that would exceed the capacity of the stack (just as a `pop()` operation would throw on an empty stack).

An example of a static implementation (though it allows setting the total capacity), might be like the following. Here the access will always be O(1) as an index is directly used, there is no traversal of the data structure, and no memory re-allocation. Note the code is example, and has not been tested. The use of the Generic could be removed if the approach in question specifies the specific type of stack (such as int or char).

```
public class AnotherStack<T>
{
  private final T[] values;
  private int loc = 0;

  // must use the suppress, as we are using a raw Object array
  //   which is necessitated as cannot make a generic array  
  // See Effective Java
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public AnotherStack(int size)
  {
    values = (T[])new Object[size];
  }


  public void push(T val)
  {
      if (loc < values.length) {
          values[loc++] = val;
      }
      else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Stack full");
      }
  }

  public T pop()
  {
      if (loc == 0) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Stack empty");
      }
      return (values[--loc]);
  }

  // other methods
}
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, for both ADTs he doesn't want them to grow as the stack is filled up. For example, the Leaky Stack is supposed to just remove the oldest elements when you add a new element to a full stack. So I think you may be right, I'm going to assume this is it, I will return tomorrow with a check mark if you are correct. Thanks!